# Refresh Index.html

Tags: refresh, html

I changed my index.htm page, close down chrome and when I reopen it's still displaying the old page. I know I can hit F5 but that's no good as users won’t know to do this. How can force chrome to stop caching the old page for all users without having to manually click F5?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:

[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

**To clear Google Chrome Cache:** 
Go to Chrome Settings (top right corner of browser) > History > History > Clear Browsing Data > (checkmark) Cached images and files.

Also make sure the address bar (URL) is pointing to the correct file you are modifying.

Comment: I have a website that I upload the new HTML page I need the users to get the new index.html. I know how to manually clear cache or refresh a page but the users wont know to do this

Comment: @tfa I see. If the users have internet connection, shouldn't the updated website automatically load the changes for the users? Apologies, I misread your question before!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it in code going forward, a refresh will occur once for every visit. Thanks for you help.

```js
if (!sessionStorage.Refreshed) {
  $window.location.reload();
  sessionStorage.Refreshed = true;
}
```